# Sort and merge 2 files without duplicate lines, based on the first column

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I have a file with all the tests name:

```
$ cat all_tests.txt
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
test6
```

And another file containing the test names and the associated result:

```
$ cat completed_tests.txt
test1 Passed
test3 Failed
test5 Passed
test6 Passed
```

How to create a new file containing all the test names with the associated result without duplicates?

If I execute:

```
sort all_tests.txt completed_tests.txt
```

The output contains duplicates:

```
test1 
test1 Passed
test2
test3 
test3 Failed
test4
test5 
test5 Passed
test6 
test6 Passed
```

The desired output:

```
test1 Passed
test2
test3 Failed
test4
test5 Passed
test6 Passed
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Seems like you can achieve this with `join` very easily if the files are both sorted.

```
$ join -a 1 all_test.txt completed_test.txt
test1 Passed
test2
test3 Failed
test4
test5 Passed
test6 Passed
```

`-a 1` means print lines from file 1 that had nothing joined to them.

If your files are not already sorted, you can use this (thanks terdon!):

```
join -a 1  <(sort all_tests.txt) <(sort completed_tests.txt )
```

Answer (score 7):

The right tool here is `join` as [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/924905/85695) by @Zanna, but here's an `awk` approach:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}{print $1,a[$1]}' completed_tests.txt all_tests.txt 
test1 Passed
test2 
test3 Failed
test4 
test5 Passed
test6 Passed
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Perl

Effectively, this is a port of terdon's answer:

```
$ perl -lane '$t+=1; $h{$F[0]}=$F[1] if $.==$t; print $F[0]," ",$h{$F[0]} if $t!=$.;$.=0 if eof' completed_tests.txt all_tests.txt          
test1 Passed
test2 
test3 Failed
test4 
test5 Passed
test6 Passed
```

This works by building hash of test-status pairs from `completed_test.txt` and then looking up lines in `all_tests.txt` in that hash. The `$t` variable of total lines processed from each file and `$.` that is reset upon reaching end of file, allow us to keep track of which file is currently read.